# Issue in virtualenv for Mac OS (M1 chip)

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv-virtualenv

I have installed the virtualenv in my macOS M1 chip using the command

`pip install virtualenv`

But when I type the virtualenv in my zsh shell is shows me the error like:

`RuntimeError: No virtualenv implementation for PythonInfo({'base_exec_prefix': None, 'system_stdlib': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 'has_venv': False, 'prefix': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', 'stdout_encoding': u'UTF-8', 'executable': '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python', 'implementation': u'CPython', 'exec_prefix': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', 'platform': u'darwin', 'version': u'2.7.16 (default, Jun 18 2021, 03:23:52) \n[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.19.59.6) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploy', 'sysconfig_paths': {u'platstdlib': u'{platbase}/lib/python{py_version_short}', u'platlib': u'{platbase}/lib/python{py_version_short}/site-packages', u'purelib': u'{base}/lib/python{py_version_short}/site-packages', u'stdlib': u'{base}/lib/python{py_version_short}', u'scripts': u'{base}/bin', u'include': u'{base}/include/python{py_version_short}', u'data': u'{base}'}, 'sysconfig_scheme': None, 'base_prefix': None, 'system_stdlib_platform': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 'file_system_encoding': u'utf-8', 'version_info': VersionInfo(major=2, minor=7, micro=16, releaselevel=u'final', serial=0), 'sysconfig_vars': {u'base': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', u'platbase': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', u'PYTHONFRAMEWORK': u'Python', u'py_version_short': u'2.7'}, 'path': [u'/usr/local/bin', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', u'/Users/shubhambansal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', u'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC'], 'max_size': 9223372036854775807, 'sysconfig': {u'makefile_filename': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile'}, 'real_prefix': None, 'distutils_install': {u'purelib': u'lib/python2.7/site-packages', u'headers': u'include/python2.7/UNKNOWN', u'platlib': u'lib/python2.7/site-packages', u'data': u'', u'scripts': u'bin'}, 'architecture': 64, 'original_executable': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python', 'os': u'posix', 'system_executable': u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'})`

Can someone please help me with the issue? Thanks